# Package com.example can't be used on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

I created my first application using Eclipse. Application is based on Google maps API v2.
I tested it and its working fine, as I wanted.

But I have problem when I try to upload it on Google play. I gave them 25 USD, I entered all info that they requested from me and now when I try to upload beta version or regular version it says that **com.example cant be used** and that I need to use different name of package. What should I do? I mean what name of package I should enter? My application name is "Trafika".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The domain com.example is restricted for Android apps. Try something like `com.djokic.trafika`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `AndroidManifest.xml`, change `com.example` to `com.trafika` (for example). Take a look at the [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#package).

Answer (score 1):

Change your package name to something else.

As warned, you cannot use **com.example.yourapplication**

May be try using **com.trafika**

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse goto your project package , select the package you want to rename and press F2 to rename it
It will update all the imports and other things.